# ASP.NET Core model binding fails for DateTime or DateOnly types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, refit, dateonly

In my ASP.NET Core 6.0 api project, I have this endpoint in the controller:

```
[HttpGet("Customers/{DateOfBirth}")]
Task<IActionResult> GetCustomers([FromRoute] DateTime? dateOfBirth, CancellationToken token){....}
```

I'm calling that endpoint with a refit client like this:

```
[Get("/Customers/{dateOfBirth}")]
public Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomersAsync(DateTime? dateOfBirth, CancellationToken token);
```

Get the `404 Bad Request` response stating model validation has failed.

> Refit.ValidationApiException: Response code does not indicate success: 404 (Bad Request).

However, no problem if I use the postman to call the api (`.../customers/01-01-1980`). I read in another SO post that the problem is the ":" in the time part.

So I tried the new `DateOnly` type from .NET 6 but this time I get the `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`.

> Refit.ValidationApiException: Response code does not indicate success: 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

I am not sure how postman is able to send the request without any issue. Obviously if I send the date as a string, no issue but I have to convert it back into `DateTime` in the controller which I want to avoid. So is this issue specific to Refit or any `HttpClient` request? I'm aware Refit is using `HttpClient` behind the scene.

Comment: I would suggest you use an int yyyyMMdd for dateonly and string for other formats then you validate and convert on the model validation at server side, adding this to a validation clientside for user handling. This will prevent any attack handle the parsing.

Comment: You can get the code from postman. Did you try that?

Comment: did yo u resolve it?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli No, I gave up and just converted the date to string before passing it to the refit client method.  The model binder in the controller correctly converts the string to DateTime.  I hope refit developers fix this issue if they haven't already.